# Firebase Cloud Functions onDelete - How to access parent's information?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

So, from Firebase functions, I'm listening to this event -

```
exports.populateVairations_delete =
functions.database.ref('/parentA/parentB/child').onDelete(event => 
{
    // I know how to get the previous value for what I'm listening too...
    val = event.data.previous.val();
    ...
}
```

This function is being invoked also when deleting the parent, which is exactly what I want.

But when deleting a parent, how do I access data from `/parentA` **before** it's being deleted?

Answer (score 1):

onDelete triggers are always executed *after* the delete has occurred.  There's no way to prevent a delete from happening with a function.  Your onDelete code will be delivered an event that contains only the data that was deleted.  The event object itself can't be used to see other parts of the database.

If you need to access other parts of the database inside a database trigger, you can use the Admin SDK to make those queries.  There is a lot of official [sample code](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/) that illustrates how to do this.

Comment: "delivered an event that contains only the data that was deleted" - but what if the deleted node is a parent of what I'm listening too, like in the example above? Is the event delivered contain the deleted object (i.e. the parent)? Doesn't it make sense to deliver the parent in this case?

Comment: By the way, I would expect that `return false` from a onDelete trigger, would prevent the deletion.

Comment: What you are describing in both cases is not what happens in the function.  There is no way to prevent the delete, and it is only delivered the data at the location of the specified path for the function.

Answer (score 1):

With `context.resource.name` you could get a string containing the data path.

Answer (score 0):

Just use Admin SDK for Firebase, You can have administrator access to the firebase Db.From there, you can do basically anything with the Firebase Db

Comment: The Admin SDK doesn't provide a way to access to deleted data. For that there is the event object, delivered by the onDelete. The problem is it points to the data I'm listening to, even though the deleted node is a parent.